# Приставки в словах "участие" и "вкусный"

Tags: словообразование, морфемика, морфемный-разбор, приставка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли приставки в словах *участие* и *вкусный*?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

Исторически — да, в современном языке — нет.

На синхронном (современном) уровне слово *участие* непроизводно, то есть считается не производным ни от какого другого слова; исторически же это существительное пришло к нам из старославянского языка, где оно было образовано с помощью суффикса -иj- от слова *участь* «доля, часть».

Похожая история и у слова *вкусный*: в современном русском это слово образовалось от существительного *вкус*, которое, в свою очередь, непроизводно. Этимологически оно заимствовано из старославянского *въкусъ* (корень здесь тот же, что и в словах *кушать*, *кусать*).

---

О том, почему *участие* я не считаю образованным от глагола *участвовать*:

> «В системе исконной русской апеллятивной аффиксации усечение как языковая техника отсутствует» — [пишет](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/o-tak-nazyvaemom-kriterii-g-o-vinokura) лингвист А. А. Кретов.

В нашем случае slava1947 предлагается именно эта модель: 1) от глагола отсекается суффикс -ова-, 2) к получившейся основе прибавляется суффикс -иj-, однако я с ней не согласен. На мой взгляд, обоснования, приведенные А. А. Кретовым, убедительны (см. статью выше), поэтому стоит рассматриваю слово *участие* в современном русском литературном языке как непроизводное.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83550/discussion-on-answer-by-aer------).

Answer (score 1):

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли приставки в словах *участие, вкусный*?

При обращении к истории слов могут обнаруживаться связи, которые уже не осознаются всеми или значительной частью носителей языка. Однако когда-то эти связи были, и кем-то они еще могут ощущаться.

Вот с этой-то, "исторической" точки зрения в словах *вкусный* и *участие* приставки могут быть выделены. Вот какое членение этих слов представлено в *"Словаре морфем русского языка"* А.И. Кузнецовой и Т.Ф. Ефремовой:

> ***в-кус-н-ый,***
>
> ***у-част-и-е.***

В словарях, опирающихся на идеи современного словообразования, приставки в этих словах не выделяются.

В слове *участие* обычно теперь выделяется корень *участ-*,  суффикс отвлечённого существительного *-и-* (вернее: *-иj-*) и окончание *-е* (вернее: *-э*).  По мнению большинства словаристов с точки зрения современного языка это предел членения.

В слове *вкусный* – корень *вкус-*, суффикс *-н-* и окончание *-ый*.

НИКЕМ из известных мне исследователей слово *участие* в синхронном анализе не считается непроизводным. Обычно его производят от слова *участвовать* (см. его первое значение в "Новом словаре русского языка" Ефремовой: УЧАСТИЕ *ср.* 1. Процесс действия по знач. глаг. *участвовать* (1)... ).

*Участие* от *участвовать* образуют и Морковкин, и Тихонов, и ...

Из *"Словообразовательного словаря русского языка"* Тихонова (М., 1990):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитайте статьи о современных взглядах на словообразование, наверняка в них найдется полезная информация по теме. Могу рекомендовать публикацию А. А. Кретова: https://cyberleninka.ru/article/v/o-tak-nazyvaemom-kriterii-g-o-vinokura.

Comment: Просмотрел (чуть-чуть).  Увидел это: "в словарях Тихонова последовательно используется критерий Винокура..." По-моему, автор статьи поддерживает Тихонова. А выдержку из словаря Тихонова см. выше в моём ответе.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно. Вся статья, в общем-то, посвящена критике традиционно навязываемого всем, кто изучает русистику, критерию Винокура. Надеюсь, это обстоятельство внесет ясность в понимании вами отношения автора статьи (см. выше) к словарю Тихонова.

Comment: Aer! В комментариях к своему ответу Вы говорили, что считаете "на синхронном (современном) уровне слово  _участие_" непроизводным, т. к. "используя толкования из МАС, можно увидеть, что так называемый критерий Винокура не соблюдается…" Сейчас Вы, вроде бы, присоединяетесь к "критике традиционно навязываемого всем, кто изучает русистику, критерия Винокура". Вы уж сами определитесь, что к чему… У меня на все эти разбирательства ни сил, ни времени, ни желания нет.

Comment: Если можете  обосновать правильность своего утверждения "**Участвова(ть)**, очевидно, не выступает мотивирующей основой для существительного **участие**", сделайте это. А пока я вижу, что Ваше мнение не совпадает с тихоновским. А Тихонову я верю чуть больше, чем Вам...

Comment: slava1947! Очень жаль, что у вас «на все эти разбирательства ни сил, ни времени, ни желания нет». Неужели при таком подходе вы рассчитываете на диалог, а не на одностороннюю демонстрацию личного превосходства? Что ж, как бы то ни было, для начала подчеркну: я не выражал свое мнение о критерии Винокура, а лишь сделал акцент на невнимательность, допущенную вами. Если бы вы нашли пять минут и прочитали статью, то причина, почему я дал на нее ссылку, стала бы вам очевидна. Из-за того, что, видимо, ваши ресурсы ограничены, приведу саму важную цитату (см. ниже).

Comment: «В системе исконной русской апеллятивной аффиксации усечение как языковая техника отсутствует». Таким образом, приводимая вами версия о происхождении сущ. _участие_ от гл. _участвовать_ опровергается. Надеюсь, теперь вам стало хотя бы чуть-чуть понятнее, почему и на каких основаниях я предложил именно тот разбор, который предложил.

Comment: _«В системе исконной русской апеллятивной аффиксации усечение как языковая техника отсутствует»_. === Aer! Правильно ли я понимаю, что не только слово _участие_, но и слова _участник_, _безучастный_, _участливый_ следует при таком подходе считать непроизводными?

Comment: slava1947! Да, при таком подходе стоит воспринимать слова _участник_, _участливый_, _участие_ как параллельные образования с общим корнем _участ-_.

Comment: Т. е. следует считать, что  **образованы эти слова не от какого-то слова, а просто от корня "участ-"?** Я-то могу принять такую точку зрения... Но рекомендовать школьникам её не буду, чего и Вам советую!

Comment: Да, от единицы _участ-_. Словообразование — не образование __от слов__, а образование __слов__. Вопрос о производности в любом случае не стоит, да и в школе это понятие, кажется, не рассматривается вовсе, так что ваши опасения мне не вполне понятны. Ответ на поставленный вопрос — в СРЛЯ в этих словах приставок нет.

Comment: И ещё. Прочитал Вашу доработанную версию ответа: _В нашем случае предлагается именно эта модель: 1) от глагола **отсекается** суффикс -ова-, 2) к получившейся основе прибавляется суффикс -иj-._ Честно говоря, не понял, чем **отсечение** отличается от **усечения**. Как говаривал мой преподаватель математики более полувека назад, "хоть _галошей_ назовите"...

Comment: В данном случае это синонимы ) Не вижу, как говорится, ничего криминального в таком употреблении этих слов, в конце концов за ним лежит одна метафора.

Comment: Да и я не вижу ничего криминального! Я только не понимаю, почему при такой замене термина слова _участие, участник и т. д._ следует начинать считать непроизводными. А именно это Вы и написали в своём ответе!!!

Comment: Нет, под предлагаемой моделью я имел в виду предлагаемую _вами_. Уточнил формулировку, спасибо.